# Why don't Operating Systems (Windows,Linux) use Relational Databases (RDBMS) Instead of File Sytems?

Tags: database, operating-system, filesystems, rdbms

We all know that most operating systems use file systems to store all data but don't you think it is more efficient to use databases as we use in websites/web apps?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Diversity.

---

First of all, if you look at the original FAT filesystem, and the original Unix filesystem, they were both key-value stores, they did not have a directory hierarchy.

Second, [this link](https://www.quora.com/Can-an-operating-system-use-database-instead-of-file-system) suggests there there are filesystems implemented with an RDBMS backend, which is tangential to your question.

Having said these, comparing RDBMS to a filesystem as storage for an OS, there are several drawbacks to using RDBMS:

**First**, RDBMS makes very strong guarantees (ACID) by means of locking, at the cost of performance. However, most programs do not require such guarantees (for examples, think of every program that works with a NoSQL DB). In comparison, POSIX makes strong-ish guarantees about metadata, but barely any guarantees about I/O. You can build an RDBMS on top of POSIX and add locking, but you can't build a filesystem on top of an RDBMS and remove locking.

**Second**, an RDBMS requires a schema. Imagine that you create a new storage volume for an OS. Instead of formatting a filesystem, you need to decide on a schema. What schema will be the most useful?

With filesystems, the "schema" is basically one table, with the columns "path", "data", and a column for each file attributes like modification time, type, and size. Using an RDBMS for this schema allows you to perform operations like mass truncate, mass rename, mass access control etc. atomically. However, it will not allow you to modify the data of the same record (file) concurrently. Nor will it allow you to implement hard links. Extended attributes or Alternate Data Streams will still have to be implemented as they are today rather than leveraging RDBMS capabilities, as well as special index logic for the path column in order to implement features like changing directory, listing directory, checking permissions for every directory in the path of a file etc., and special logic for the data column because files can be TBs in size. At that point the ROI of RDBMS is going down the more you add features.

Alternatively you can have the schema be per-program (i.e. every program can do `CREATE TABLE` etc.), but then your features are again limited by what the RDBMS can do. For example, how do you get the equivalent of `find / -size +1GB` or `md5sum`, or even `cat` or `ls`? which columns will these programs read? You'll find that all generic programs now need to take a set of columns that are of interest. It also makes scripting much harder.

**Thirdly**, Hierarchical systems are typically easier to scale.

One example is when you want to add storage. In a hierarchical filesystem, even without any fancy filesystem features, you can simply mount another filesystem onto a directory, and you have new storage. The tradeoff vs increasing the storage capacity for the current filesystem is that hard links & renames don't work across filesystem, and they don't share the storage capacity. However, on an RDBMS your options are either to create a new table and have your programs/scripts manage both tables, or to add more storage volume, for which you might need to do more advanced things like partitioning.

Another example is ecosystem requirements. As an end user wanting to put some order into their 60,000 pictures, 5000 songs, hundreds of work spreadsheets, 10,000 memes, hundreds of eBooks, videos etc. - things that are convenient to arrange in a hierarchy - you currently only need two programs - a file manager (Explorer, bash, Nautilus etc.), and a search capability (e.g. `find(1)`). On an RDBMS, you either have different tables with different columns, or one table with generic columns. Either way, you have to have a set of SQL scripts to work with these specific collections, which would be equivalent to having a shell script or a program for each type of collection. Meaning, managing large collections requires more programming.

Since hierarchical systems are useful in a generic context (which is the context the major OSes operate in), and since it's easier to build a non-hierarchical system on top of hierarchical one than doing the other way around (hierarchical filesystem cache even makes the job easier for [libsqlfs](https://github.com/guardianproject/libsqlfs)), it is valuable for OSes to support hierarchical systems first-class.

---

**The executive summary is**: OSes serve many use cases, and storage access is a major part of that. It would be wise for an OS to build a storage access mechanism that's as minimal as possible, but that allows applications to build more specialized storage access mechanism on top of the OS.

That means providing a small but useful set of features (like permissions, locking, mounting, and symlinks) but not force too much requirements (like locking, or specifying the data format to the OS).

RDBMSes are just too specific.